# passing struct variable name in write api ()

Tags: c, sockets

There was problem in receiving and processing the packets because i used to send just a buffer not 'saddr' and its 'size' 
Hence i used structure to declare all the members ow instead of the field buffer in write() api i need to send the struct variable name .  do i need to use pointer there?

```
 struct fields
 { 
     unsigned char buffer[1024];

     socklen_t saddr_size;
 } data;
```

Comment: '&data' **is** a pointer and yes, you must use &data as an argument to the `write` function. But in your code the variable `data`s is not initialized.

Comment: Uhum, that doesn't really compile. Seems you haven't started to use the `data` struct in your call to `recvfrom`.

Comment: oh thank you sir. but how do i initialize it? may be m asking stupid question but am unable to understand.

Comment: You must put some data in your `data` variable. If you dont, `data` contains random garbage. In you small program you just declare `data` but you never do anything with it before calling the write function.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck u mean to say i need to include 'data' in the recvfrom() func sir?

Comment: Yes. There is no variable called just `buffer`. Use `&data` or `data.buffer`. `&saddr` becomes `&data.saddr`, `&saddr_size`becomes  `&data.saddr_size`.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck sir I edited as u said, but am getting the warning in the recvfrom() i.e.warning: passing argument 2 of ‘recvfrom’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]

Comment: @user2971609 typecast it to `struct fields`.

Comment: still the same error.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck without using &data.saddr and &saddr_size in recvfrom func .can we use the struct variable name in any other way ,to use it in write api()??

Comment: You can't have edited it as I said. I tested it without warning. `data.buffer` is of type `unsigned char*` which is compatible with `void*`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `recvfrom` returns the length of the message.

```
 n = recvfrom(sock,buffer,1024,0,(struct sockaddr *)&from, &length);       
 if (n < 0) error("recvfrom");
```

Here `length` is the size of the socket structure you are using. This must be  initialized prior to the call to `recvfrom` so that the kernel knows how much space is available to return the socket address.

also, note that `(struct sockaddr *)&from` will have the address of the remote socket used to send the datagram.

Now, in your call

```
data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 1024, 0 , &saddr , (socklen_t*)&saddr_size);
int cont= write(logfile,&data,data_size);
```

`data_size` will have the length of the message. But, size of `data` structure is more than the size of data_size. so, `write` may not write complete data to the `logfile`.

and make a note of Klas Lindbäck's comment. That is what you needed.

Please see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093268/doubt-in-defining-structure-in-c-socket-program/20094282#20094282).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct fields
     {
        unsigned char buffer[1024];
        struct sockaddr saddr;
        socklen_t saddr_size;
     } data;

 int main()
     {
         int saddr_size;
         struct fields data;   // Note: this variable will hide the global variabledata.
         struct sockaddr saddr;
         ssize_t data_size;
         int sock_raw, logfile=1;

         // Need to insert code to create raw socket.

         data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw, data.buffer, 1024, 0, &data.saddr,
                         &data.saddr_size);
         int cont = write(logfile, &data, sizeof data);

         return 0;
     }
```

Comment: don't you think the return value of `recvfrom` i.e., data_size is less than the size of `data`.

Comment: @Raju You are right. I'm changing so I write a fixed length. This probably isn't what he really needs, though. He needs to redesign the protocol (i.e. the file structure). I consider that to be outside the scope of the question.

Comment: of course that isn't what he needed for now.. but it may cause loss of data and he may post the same question again..Anyhow, your code seems fine.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck i have created the socket and related stuff sir. i just uploaded the line of code which is related to my question.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck actually my professor tells me not to modify the recvfrom func i.e '&data.buffer' etc. He has asked me to use the struct variable name before the write api() and after recvfrom() func which will probably be used in write api instead of sending buffer. i dont know how do i do it!! ?