# Doubt in defining structure in c socket program

Tags: c, sockets

```
  data_size = recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 1024, 0 , &saddr ,
                                               (socklen_t*)&saddr_size);
```

Here is a recvfrom function, where I want to create a struct to 'saddr' and 'saddr_size' which is declared in the `main()` as follows

```
  struct sockaddr saddr;
  int saddr_size;
  saddr_size = sizeof saddr;
```

and instead of buffer mentioned in the below `write()` api I have to use the struct variable.

```
  int cont= write(logfile,buffer,data_size);
```

My question is: Below I have used structure. Is this the way to define struct for the following fields? Is it declared correctly? If not please somebody guide me to correct it.

```
  struct data{ 
      unsigned char buffer[1024];
      unsigned long int saddr; 
      //   struct sockaddr saddr;
      int saddr_size;
  };
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Exchange! this should be on Stack Overflow - on Unix & Linux, we don't like to answer programming questions unless they're about APIs or interfaces specific to *nix systems, or if it's a shell programming question. this is neither, so I'm flagging it for a move.

Comment: Are you in **doubt** or you have a **question**? :)

Comment: The struct looks proper. Are you facing any issue with this? 1024 in `recvfrom`may need to be changed to proper `sizeof(struct data)`..

Comment: @haccks yeah doubt isn't cleared yet.

Comment: what I assume is .. you received the buffer from a network and you want to store the buffer, the network socket address and sizeof the socket structure received in to a log file. is this your question ..??

Comment: @user2971609 you got any solution..?? or do you still have a problem..??

Comment: @RajuKundhe No i dint :( hence have uploaded again the entire code here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20114009/how-to-copy-the-struct-variables-into-buffer-in-c-socket-program] . Can you please give me the suggestion where am i going wrong?

Comment: `saddr_size` should better be of type `socklen_t`.

Answer (score 2):

I assumed this as your structure.

```
struct fields{ 
    unsigned char msg[1024];      // buffer received.
    char saddr[14];               // network socket address received.
    int sock_size;                // sizeof socket structure.
}data;
```

After the `recvfrom` call, define/initialize your structure variables(i.e., copy buffer,network address, size to the structure fields).

Now, log the structure data to the file

```
fprintf(logfile,"%s %s %d",data.msg,data.saddr.address,data.saddr_size);
```